# WebStorm Docker deamon connection error on Macbook M1

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, webstorm, apple-m1

I have a MacBook M1 and installed WebStorm 2022.2.3 and installed Docker plugin. Then I installed Docker Desktop for Apple Silicon.

The Docker Desktop is working fine but in my WebStorm I got an error when I try to build a `.yaml` file. The error is that WebStorm cannot connect to the Docker daemon.

I’ve searched for a solution for this error online but had no luck. I installed Brew and Rosetta 2 and the issue is the same.

Has anyone had this kind of issue? Oh, I did not mention that on my Windows laptop this feature works normally :-)

[image]

Comment: Please see if https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-258012/Cannot-connect-to-the-Docker-daemon-at-unixvarrundockersock-Is-the-docker-daemon-running#focus=Comments-27-5461772.0-0 helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Docker Desktop for Apple Silicon seems to place the socket at a different place (in the users domain, not in system domain):
When Docker Desktop is not running, `docker` shows the error

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///Users/"your_username"/.docker/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

So there are two ways to solve the problem:

1. configure TCP-Socket instead of "Docker for Mac"
   [image]
2. Symlink the expected system socket path to your personal socket

   > sudo ln -s /Users/your_username/.docker/run/docker.sock /var/run/

the later is only suitable if there is only a single user using Docker an a computer so Docker Desktop is always started by the same user.

There is no need to install another docker with `brew`.

Comment: Thanks the TCP-Socket with the unix:/// way worked for me =)

Answer (score 0):

After trying lots of things I finally manage to get it worked. I completely removed the Docker Desktop, then install again Docker Desktop, and in the terminal run:

```
brew install docker-machine docker
```

After this it worked, and the WebStorm status is now 'Connection successfully'